# how to retrive xml data using sax parser

Tags: xml-parsing

I have plain xml file, which don't have any NameSpace. I want to read the xml file and put into bean. I am not able to read the xml data line by line. So please help me to read xml using sax parser.

Regards
Narsi.

Answer (score 0):

> "So please help me to read xml using sax parser."

Ok, what questions do you have? Have you tried looking at examples?

Are you working with the SAX Java implementation? C++? ?

Sax Parser is an event based XML parsing utility. One of the fundamental purposes of SAX is that it is light on memory, the entire document will not be stored in memory once the file is read.

> "I am not able to read the xml data line by line."

What do you mean line by line? If you want to read a file "line by line", you could simply use a regular file input stream. SAX provides notifications when certain events are occurring during the parsing of the file (i.e. started reading document, started reading element, ended element, etc, etc.)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML

Comment: i am working with SAX java implementation. My Xml file have limited data. I need examples to read xml and put into bean using SAX parser.

Comment: Here is a start: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/